# jQuery captcha match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a jQuery and php captcha after i add the code to validate the match its not working

here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img#captcha-refresh').click(function() {
    change_captcha();
    });

    function change_captcha(){
        document.getElementById('captcha').src="reCaptcha/get_captcha.php?rnd=" + Math.random();
    }

    var captchascr = $('#captcha').attr('src');

     $('#captcha-code').on('change', function(){
         var captchaval = $(this).val();
            if (captchascr == captchaval) {
                console.log('match');
                }else {
                    console.log('No match');
                    }
         });
});
```

html

```
    <div class="captcha-box"> 
        <img src="reCaptcha/get_captcha.php" id="captcha" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-box">
        <label>Type the two words:</label>
        <input name="captcha-code" type="text" id="captcha-code">
    </div>
    <div class="captcha-action">
        <img src="reCaptcha/refresh.jpg" id="captcha-refresh" />
    </div>
```

here is the php code

```
session_start();
$word_1 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_1 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_2 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}
$_SESSION['random_number'] = $word_1.' '.$word_2;
$dir = 'fonts/';
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);
$font = "recaptchaFont.ttf"; // font style
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);// color
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0,0, 709, 99, $white);
imagettftext ($image, 22, 0, 5, 30, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['random_number']);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image)
```

here is the session is created at the php file  i just don't know how to call the session so i make the matching, can someone please help?

Comment: According to your code, I assume that the `reCaptcha/get_captcha.php` will return a captcha image. 

Now this statement `var captchascr = $('#captcha').attr('src');` will give the image src path that is `reCaptcha/get_captcha.php`
And you are matching it with the text value, so it will not work.

Comment: ok i got your point thanks for the tip now what to do ?

Comment: You can to use `session` to store value generated by this page `reCaptcha/get_captcha.php`. And on the submit or check button click, you can make an `AJAX` call to the value checking function in the other `php` file according to the `AJAX` response you can validate the captcha value.

Comment: yes there is a session at the php code just don't know to to call it, i have add the php code

Comment: Refer to this link : [http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/). There is a demo given how to use the `jQuery AJAX`

Comment: i add this code $.ajax({ url: 'reCaptcha/get_captcha.php', type: 'GET', success: function(data) { console.log(data);},}); BUT i'm getting many textat the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `AJAX` Call to the new file named `validate_captcha.php`.

The **PHP Code** in file to handle **AJAX Call**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $task       = !empty($_POST['task']) ? $_POST['task'] : null;
    $response   = 'false';
    if ( $task == 'validateCaptha' ){
        $inputCaptcha       = !empty($_POST['inputCaptcha']) ? $_POST['inputCaptcha'] : null;
        $sessionCaptcha     = $_SESSION['random_number'];

        if ($inputCaptcha   == $sessionCaptcha){
            $response   = 'true';
        }else{
            $response   = 'false';
        }
        echo $response; 
        exit();
    }

?>
```

**The jQuery AJAX Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img#captcha-refresh').click(function() {
        change_captcha();
        });

        function change_captcha(){
            document.getElementById('captcha').src="reCaptcha/get_captcha.php?rnd=" + Math.random();
        }

$('#captcha-code').on('change', function(){
    var inputCaptcha = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    url: 'reCaptcha/validate_captcha.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: {'task':'validateCaptha', 'inputCaptcha':inputCaptcha},
    success: function(response){
        if (response=='true'){
            alert('Match');
        }else{
            alert('Not Match');
        }
    }

});
         });
});
```

Hope this may help you.